# How to suppress spellcheck on a string constant in Android Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-lint

Android Lint picks up the string constant in this code sample as a spelling error on "dWQGSCDx". According to the docs I should use @SupressLint("Typos") to suppress it but that doesn't achieve that. I see others have suggested using @SuppressWarnings but that is not working either.

```
/**
 * Constants.kt
 */

import android.annotation.SuppressLint

@SuppressLint("Typos")
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")    
const val SOME_STRING_VALUE = "...dWQGSCDx..."
```

Note this is a file-scoped global constant, it is not inside a class so an annotation cannot be placed on a containing class.

How do I suppress spell-checking of this constant definition without disabling spellcheck entirely and without adding the "mispelt" text to the dictionary?

Comment: I am struggling for the same thing, probably it is a bug in Kotlin or the IDE itself.

Comment: Have you tried adding this word to IDE's dictionary? it should be in the suggestion list to fix it

Comment: @elmorabea As I said in the question, I need a solution that does NOT involve putting the text in the dictionary.

Comment: This appears to be Kotlin-specific. The @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection") annotation does suppress the spelling warning, but only in Java and not Kotlin. I've reported it as a bug. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70615542  Please star the bug if you see the same issue.

Comment: Ollie - This doesn't work in latest IntelliJ with raw Kotlin (no Android).
Also, @elmorabea if you have stuff in your tests (like testing Base64 encoded values), then you don't want to add each encoded string to the dictionary, I'm guessing that's the case with OP too.

Answer (score 18):

In Kotlin you can suppress this warning using `@Suppress` instead of `@SuppressWarnings` with the following annotation

```
@Suppress("SpellCheckingInspection")
```

Comment: That works, but I have to repeat this line before every Class, that is annoying, is there a way to suppress spell checking globally for a whole project?

Comment: You can disable spellchecking in Android Studio or IntelliJ in `Preferences` - `Editor` - `Inspections`